# sqlite query simple select query

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm new to `sqlite` query. can anyone tell me how can I get some specific row set by select ?

my_table

```
+------------+--------------+----------+
| client_id  | product_type |   value  |
+============+==============+==========+
|    2       |     2        | Server   |    
|    2       |     4        | Domain   | 
|    2       |     2        | Hosting  |     
|    3       |     2        | Dialer   |    
|    2       |     3        | Drive    |
+------------+--------------+----------+
```

how can i get `client_id` and `product_type` like below only the below rowset--

```
+-------------+---------------+
| client_id   | product_type  |
+=============+===============+
|    2        |     3         |   
|    3        |     2         |
+-------------+---------------+
```

Comment: 3 | 2 .. sorry for the mistake.

Comment: What sets apart the rows that you keep from the rows that you wish to filter out?

Comment: i want only distinct client_id and other column should select normally without distinct. @dasblinkenlight

Comment: For client_id 2, what basis u want 3 as product_type?

Comment: Why client `2` should get product `3`, as opposed to, say, 2 or 4?

Comment: not a very clear one

Answer (score 0):

### **QUERY**

```
sqlite> SELECT client_id,product_type
...> FROM client
...> GROUP BY client_id;
```

### **[CHECK THIS DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/0f2f2/2)**

---

[image]

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT sensor_id,event_type FROM events group by sensor_id ORDER BY sensor_id ASC;
```

Comment: Where did you get these values from??? Your question has a different table with different column names and data.